# Specify multiple facet fields in DSE Search CQL solr_query

Tags: solr, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-3.0, cql3

Let us take for example we have the below table,

```
CREATE TABLE test.employee_copy1 (
  empid int,
  deptid int,
  firstname text,
  lastname text,
  solr_query text, -- column got created by enabling DSE Search
  PRIMARY KEY (empid, deptid)
)
```

Assume solrconfig.xml, schema.xml have all the fields and solr core is up and running behind cassandra in **DSE Search** environment.

When I try the following query,

```
SELECT JSON * FROM test.employee_copy1 WHERE 
solr_query = '{"q":"*:*", 
"facet":{"field":"firstname"}}'; // LOOK HERE
```

I get result as, **EXPECTED**

```
{
    "facet_fields": {
        "firstname": {
            "John": 154,
            "Mary": 77
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I want facets for both firstname and lastname. Hence my query will be,

```
SELECT JSON * FROM test.employee_copy1 WHERE 
solr_query = '{"q":"*:*", 
"facet":{"field":"firstname", "field":"lastname"}}'; //LOOK HERE
```

Now the result is, **UNEXPECTED OR ERROR**

```
{
    "facet_fields": {
        "lastname": {
            "Paul": 130,
            "Abraham": 50
        }
    }
}
```

**Problem: DSE Search CQL resultset JSON doesn't return facets for both firstname and lastname. Facets are returned for only the *last field* in query.**

I also tried below queries but dev center reported **ERROR**,

```
SELECT JSON * FROM test.employee_copy1 WHERE 
solr_query = '{"q":"*:*", "facet":{"field":["firstname","lastname"]}}';

SELECT JSON * FROM test.employee_copy1 WHERE 
solr_query = '{"q":"*:*", "facet":{"field":"firstname,lastname"}}';
```

> **Question:** Can DSE Search handle only one facet field?

Note: I am able to pass two fields to Solr HTTP API and get facets for both fields as below.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/test.employee/select?q=*:*&wt=json&indent=true&facet=true&facet.field=firstname&facet.field=lastname

  RESPONSE:
  ...
    {
        "facet_fields": {
            "firstname": [
                "John", 
                 154,
                "Mary", 
                77
             ],
            "lastname": [
                "Paul", 
                 130,
                "Abraham", 
                50
             ]
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What version of DSE are you using?

Comment: Also, does your `SELECT` work without specifying `JSON`?

Comment: Finally, if you execute `SELECT JSON * FROM test.employee_copy1 WHERE solr_query = '{"q":"*:*", "facet":{"field":["firstname","lastname"]}}';` directly in `cqlsh`, what error/result are you presented with?

Comment: Q1. ans -> DSE5.0.1; Q2. Yes select * also returns the same JSON;

Comment: To expand on why I asked about `cqlsh`, I want to rule out DevCenter as a potential source of the problem. I'm not able to reproduce your problem on 5.0.8 with queries that use the syntax `"facet":{"field":["firstname","lastname"]}` against `cqlsh`.

Comment: Q3: answer -> query returns both facets when I execute from cqlsh. Do you think that this is a dev center bug?

Comment: Do you think that datastax java client will have any problem executing facet for multiple fields?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147408/discussion-between-arun-bc-and-caleb-rackliffe).